# Struggling to get re-base to recognise my initialized firebase DB

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working through some ReactJS tutorials, I've gone through them before but I'm having a bit of a refresh because it's been a while since I've had any reason to use ReactJS at all. *Something* has changed with firebase / rebase since the last time I looked at it, and the sample code does not do the job I need it to do any more.

This is the code using the compatibility versions of firebase

```
import Rebase from 're-base';
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/database';

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: "xxx",
  authDomain: "xxx.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://xxx.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app",
});

const base = Rebase.createClass(firebaseApp.database());

export { firebaseApp }

export default base;
```

This is the error this approach produces:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'database')
```

This is the firebase V9 approach:

```
import Rebase from 're-base';
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getDatabase } from 'firebase/database';

const firebaseApp = initializeApp({
  apiKey: "xxx",
  authDomain: "xxx.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://xxx.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app",
});

const base = Rebase.createClass(getDatabase(firebaseApp));

export { firebaseApp }

export default base;
```

This is the error I'm getting for the v9 approach:

```
REBASE: Rebase.createClass failed. Expected an initialized firebase or firestore database object.
```

As far as I can tell, the DB initialises fine. I've tried the whole firebase / initialize app / get database steps from within another component and console logged out what looks like a database object to me (but newbie caveats apply here)

What am I missing? Is there some obvious configuration step with the DB that I've overlooked?

How can I confirm that my firebase DB is actually initialized at all? Why is Rebase being such a pain in the backside?

for reference:

> firebase: v9.9.4 / rebase: v4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@efreeman, your issue is the update to Firebase 9. You need to use Firebase 8.10.0 that is provided in the course `starter files`.

https://github.com/wesbos/React-For-Beginners-Starter-Files/blob/master/catch-of-the-day/package.json

You can revert your `package.json` file and re-install the npm packages.

`Re-base` is not compatible with `Firebase 9`

Comment: Ah, couldn't see anywhere where re-base is no longer compatible with v9, that'll be what's stopping me then - I wanted to try and learn rather than leaning on older versions to get through the tutorials (which I've run through a few times previously, but keep going over it a few months later as a refresher) - I figure things always change, and I wanted to try to change with it and understand what each element was doing. I'll revert to the older version and go from there for now then, and try to wrap my head around alternatives!

Love that you could tell what tutorials I was using! Thank you